# Monitoring status of ipyparallel completion

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

I have a function that takes a while to calculate, and has to be iterated >20k times with two varying parameters:

```
from ipyparallel import Client
import numpy as np

m_array = np.arange(0, 101, 1)
s_array = np.arange(0, 201, 1)
rc = Client()
rc[:].push(dict(stuff=stuff))
view = rc.load_balanced_view()
async_results = []

for m in m_array:
    for s in s_array:
        chi = view.apply_async(run_simulation, m=m, s=s)
        async_results.append(chi)
rc.wait(async_results)
results = [ar.get() for ar in async_results]
```

I see there is a [wait_interactive](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncresult.html) method available, however I have not been able to figure out how to use it. What's the best way to print out a status update at some given interval?

**Update**

I added the `all_ids` list, and the `get_result().wait_interative()` methods.

```
async_results = []
all_ids = []
for m in m_array:
    for s in s_array:
        chi = view.apply_async(run_simulation, m=m, s=s)
        async_results.append(chi)
        all_ids.extend(chi.msg_ids)
rc.get_result(all_ids).wait_interactive()
rc.wait(async_results)
results = [ar.get() for ar in async_results]
```

This produces the periodic status updates as expected, however now produces a traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-85db6ca605cd> in <module>()
    220 rc.get_result(all_ids).wait_interactive()
    221 rc.wait(async_results)
--> 222 results = [ar.get() for ar in async_results]
223 results = np.array(results)
224 results.shape = (len(m_array), len(s_array))

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/asyncresult.pyc in get(self, timeout)
     95         by get() inside a `RemoteError`.
     96         """
---> 97         if not self.ready():
     98             self.wait(timeout)
     99 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/asyncresult.pyc in ready(self)
    113         """Return whether the call has completed."""
    114         if not self._ready:
--> 115             self.wait(0)
    116         elif not self._outputs_ready:
    117             self._wait_for_outputs(0)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/asyncresult.pyc in     wait(self, timeout)
    152                 if self.owner:
    153 
--> 154                     self._metadata = [self._client.metadata.pop(mid) for mid in self.msg_ids]
155                     [self._client.results.pop(mid) for mid in self.msg_ids]
    156 

KeyError: '884328c8-d768-48d5-b477-a256ebaea7a9'
```

Are the message IDs or results being cleared out somewhere before the `ar.get()` method gets to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wait_interactive is a method on AsyncResult objects. It will be a method on the Client itself soon, but is not currently. That means to use wait_interactive, you need to build an AsyncResult wrapping all of your results. The easiest way to do this is to maintain a single list of all msg_ids corresponding to your requests:

```
all_ids = []
for m in m_array:
    for s in s_array:
        chi = view.apply_async(run_simulation, m=m, s=s)
        async_results.append(chi)
        all_ids.extend(chi.msg_ids)

rc.get_result(all_ids, owner=False).wait_interactive()
```

Comment: I added the all_id's list, and the rc.get_result().wait_interactive line, but am now getting another traceback. See the update above

Comment: added missing `owner=False` argument that may be needed to avoid removing entries from the cache.